# CalendarWeekRule is different for the same culture on different operating system

Tags: c#, .net, windows

As the title say, when I checked the `CalendarWeekRule` for cs-CZ, it returns `FirstDay` on Windows 7 but on Windows 10 it returns `FirstFourDayWeek`

From what I can find, this is dependent on the OS and .NET version. But I'm not sure if it is dependent on both or either one.

What I want right now is some supporting evidence to show that Microsoft changed this somewhere. Does anyone know where they mentioned this? Or at least some good article explaining the situation?

Only piece of info I found so far is this [Showing wrong CalendarWeekRule for en-GB | exceptionin.com](http://exceptionin.com/q/showing-wrong-calendarweekrule-for-en-gb/)

[image]